# Compute upper convex hull of a function surface

Tags: convex-hull

I have a sampled function sruface

$$
z = f(x, y)
$$

represented as a grayscale raster image. How to find the upper convex hull of that surface. That is I am looking for the minimal

$$
g(x, y)
$$

such that

$$
g(x, y) \geq f(x, y),
\text{Eigenvalues}(\text{Hessian}(g)) < 0
$$

It is possible to convert the image into a 3d mesh, and then use qhull or similar, but that would result in too much overhead.

Comment: Why do you think that qhull is inappropriate ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Memory concerns. Converting a large image (16 MP) to a mesh will take a lot of memory.

Comment: Then roll your own qhull using the points straight from the image. The hull should be much more compact (unless your surface is already convex).

Comment: Note that a convex hull algorithm does not need a mesh but just points. If they are represented on 3 ints or floats, this is 12 bytes per point.

Comment: @YvesDaust And then you need to construct a triangulation, followed by a polygonal fill.

Comment: "followed by a polygonal fill": hem, if you want the convex hull on every pixel, that is unavoidable. So if you don't have enough memory, you just can't solve this problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought there could be a shortcut, when you have some more information about the data, but I realized a problem. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that there is a problem with the convex hull of a raster image, namely the fact that it is essentially constructed of quads, which gives an ambiguity. For example, consider the example below:

```
0   1

1   0
```

This could be interprted like

```
0 -- 1
|  / |
| /  |
1 -- 0
```

```
0 -- 1
| \  |
|  \ |
1 -- 0
```

Which obviously results in a different upper convex hull. Thus, a general convex hull algorithm would be required.